# Terminology for uniqueness up to unique morphism

Tags: category-theory, terminology

If $S$ is any sub"collection" of a category $C$, we say it is *unique up to isomorphism* if all its objects are isomorphic, and *unique up to unique isomorphism* if those isomorphisms are unique.

Examples of the latter are given by the collections of initial or terminal objects. These have the stronger property that they are *unique up to unique morphism*. I.e. there is a unique morphism between each two, which necessarily is an isomorphism. Equivalently, their endomorphism monoids are trivial.

This is stronger than and not equivalent to uniqueness up to unique isomorphism, consider for example the groups of order 2.

> **Question.** Is there another term for something being *unique up to unique morphism*?

Comment: Universal, most likely

Comment: Note that these are just the isomorphism classes of any object with only a single automorphism.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Endomorphism, yes.

Comment: @barto, no, automorphism. Groups of order 2 have 2 endomorphisms.

Comment: @MeesdeVries All right, so your comment was about u.u.t.u. isomorphism.